# Irreducibility in $\operatorname{Proj}S$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

$\newcommand{\proj}{\operatorname{Proj}}\newcommand{\spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}$
It is well know that in $\spec A$, $V(I)$ is irreducible if and only if $\sqrt{I}$ is a prime ideal. Is it also true for $\proj S$? Using the standard argument, here is as far as I can show:

> If $V_+(J)$ is irreducible and $I,K\subset S$ are graded ideals such that $IK\subset\sqrt{J}$, then $I_+\subset\sqrt{J}$ or $K_+\subset\sqrt{J}$.

This is not quite sufficient to say that $\sqrt{J}$ is a prime.

**Edit:** For $\operatorname{Proj}S$, the ideals are assumed to be graded, and $I_+:=I\cap S_+$. $V_+(I)$ is the set of all graded prime ideals not containing $S_+$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not true: consider the ring $S=(\mathbb{Z}/(6))[x]$ and its prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}=(\bar{2})[x]$.

$V_+(\mathfrak{p})=V_+(\mathfrak{p}_+)$ is irreducible, but $\sqrt{\mathfrak{p}_+}\subset S$ is not a prime ideal; to see this, first note that the nilradical of the ring $\mathbb{Z}/(6)$ is the zero ideal.

This implies $\sqrt{\mathfrak{p}_+}=\mathfrak{p}_+$, and $\mathfrak{p}_+\subset S$ is not a prime ideal since $\bar{2},\bar{3}\not\in\mathfrak{p}_+$ but $\bar{2}\cdot\bar{3}=\bar{0}\in\mathfrak{p}_+$.

Comment: I've thought you are working in polynomial rings over *fields*.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can firstly put all the prime homogeneous ideals into affine case,in fact the topology on $P^n$ and that of (n+1)-dimensional are compatible. So you can prove that the set of all ireducible algebraic sets and the set of all prime like $\sqrt{J}$
are 1-1 corresponing to one another just like in the affine case.